# How can I solve this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors

I have this code. Eclipse tells me that the syntax is correct but when I run the program it gives me this error:

How can I solve this error exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.\<init\>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.\<init\>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:167)<br/>
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:200)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:126)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.\<init\>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.\<init\>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
```